# "resultIndex is -1, the polygon must be invalid!" after addView()

Tags: android, android-view

I get an exception after calling addView() method on ViewGroup (FrameLayout).

```
public final View createView(Context context, Property property, ViewGroup parent) {
        mView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(getLayout(), null);
        mContext = context;
        mProperty = property;
        processBaseViews(mView, property);
        processViews(mView, property);
        parent.addView(mView);
        return mView;
    }
```

Exception:

```
10-17 18:39:40.060: E/OpenGLRenderer(511): resultIndex is -1, the polygon must be invalid!
10-17 18:39:40.061: A/libc(511): Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0x136 in tid 726 (hwuiTask1)
```

This code works normally on Android Lollipop (SDK <= 22), but closes with error on Android Marshmallow (SDK 23). How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've just started running into the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was receiving the same error also same case, the code works fine in api<23 only crashes on api 23
what I found is in my code i was setting custom animation to a fragment BEFORE replace.() but after **FIRST** replacing and **THEN** setting custom animation just worked for me. here is my code snippet

```
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Had the same issue on a rooted device running Android 6.0. This fixed it.

Comment: Brilliant! You just save'd my day.

Comment: Perhaps this disable the animation completely on every API version. I solved by not setting the custom animation just for API 23.

Answer (score 2):

This bug happens when you try to start animating a view that isn't attached to the layout yet.

However, there seems to be a missed corner where in certain cases in API 23 (Marshmellow), when you try to animate a certain views with elevation set, it will close the app no matter what.

Let's say the following is your current code:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:elevation="@dimen/custom_elevation" />
```

```
   container.animate()
            .scaleX(1f)
            .scaleY(1f)
            .setListener(null)
            .start();
```

In that case, you have couple options for the workaround:

1. Remove elevation from the view
2. Remove animation that contains elevation
3. Remove elevation just for API 23
4. Remove animation just for API 23
5. Remove elevation temporarily and add the elevation back after the animation finishes:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:id="@+id/container"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
   container.animate()
            .scaleX(1f)
            .scaleY(1f)
            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                    final float elevation = container.getDimension(R.dimen.custom_elevation);
                    container.setElevation(elevation);
                }
            })
            .start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the identical error, only with API 23 and only on real devices, see my issue https://github.com/davideas/FlipView/issues/9

In my case, it seems setting *elevation* in the layout, it breaks the flip animation.

Workaround solution: I've removed the *elevation* where it was not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The thread might be a bit old, but I came across the same problem while trying to animate a `CardView`on a Honor device. Changing the `CardView`to a `LinearLayout` fixed the issue (so it might have to do with the default elevation of a `CardView`.

Hope it can help someone !

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was setting `cameraDistance` for an upcoming property animator on a non added child of ViewGroup like this:

```
firstView.cameraDistance = firstView.width * 10f
```

The width was not present of course, as the view was not yet added and layouted (stupid mistake) which led to a cameraDistance of 0.

This results in the same error message:

> “resultIndex is -1, the polygon must be invalid!”